# Show $\cos(\pi/11)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-numbers

Show $\cos(\pi/11)$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$

I am trying to follow the answers in [How to prove that $\cos (2\pi/n)$ is algebraic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257811/how-to-prove-that-cos-2-pi-n-is-algebraic)

So  $\cos(\pi/11)+ i\sin(\pi/11)$ is a root of $x^{22}=1$ and so $\cos(\pi/11)+ i\sin(\pi/11)$ is algebraic. Since, sums and scalar multiples are algebraic then  $\cos(\pi/11)$ is algebraic. Is that right?

Comment: You need to be explicit how you get $\cos(\pi/11)$ as the sum or product of algebraic numbers.

Comment: $\cos x=\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$.

Comment: Because $\cos(\pi/11) + i \sin(\pi/11)$ and $\cos(\pi/11) - i \sin(\pi/11)$ are algebraic, then $\cos(\pi/11) + i \sin(\pi/11) + \cos(\pi/11) - i \sin(\pi/11)$ is algebraic. But be careful: $3 = \pi - (\pi - 3)$ is algebraic, but $\pi$ is not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to follow that argument. But $\cos\left(\frac\pi{11}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi{11}\right)$ is indeed a root of $x^{22}-1$. And so is $\cos\left(\frac\pi{11}\right)-i\sin\left(\frac\pi{11}\right)$. But then their sum, which is $2\cos\left(\frac\pi{11}\right)$, is algebraic. So, $\cos\left(\frac\pi{11}\right)$ is algebraic.